# $\lim x^{2/3} -(x^2+1)^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the limit

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{2/3} -(x^2+1)^{1/3}$$

I've tried:

$$\lim x^{2/3} -(x^2+1)^{1/3} = \lim x^{2/3} \cdot \lim \left[1 - \left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/3} \right] = \infty \cdot 0$$

Any help, please?

Comment: For large $x$:$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=1+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x^2}+o \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have with the Taylor approximation $(1+u)^\alpha\sim_01+\alpha u$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{2/3} -(x^2+1)^{1/3}=\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{2/3}\left(1 -(1+x^{-2})^{1/3}\right)=-\frac13\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{2/3}x^{-2}=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: rewrite the expression as $x^3 - a^3 = (x-a)(x^2 + ax +a^2)$ where $x= x^{\frac{1}{3}}, a = 1$, i.e. multiply both numerator and denominator by some expression. What do you get?